# How do I smoothly play FLV video while loading assets in the background?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, flv, apache-flex

Working on a 'video heavy' Flash site that has an intro video.
While the intro video is playing, assets(images,flv files) should be loaded in the background.
The problem is that, while the assets are loading, the intro video play gets jittery.

What can I do to make the video playing smoothly while still loading assets?

It might be the single threaded nature of actionscript, not sure.
Any suggestion would help.

After using @Demian Brecht suggested method, I noticed that the culprit might be Memory allocation. As the FLVs load the memory usage goes up by ~266MB and while the videos are written to memory, the framerate drops to 1FPS.

I imagine I could first load all the videos and after they're in memory could display the intro video, but ideally I would need some sort of workaround to load the rest of the videos while the intro is playing.

Hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no "nice" way to deal with your problem nicely due, as you mentioned, to the single threaded nature of ActionScript.

I'd maybe move your video to begin playing in a post asset loading state and rely on a good old progress bar while loading.

A purely theoretical thought...

What if you had two embedded swf's on a page, one hidden and one playing the intro movie? Through javascript/flash interop, you could conceivably kick off loading the assets in your hidden swf once the intro video starts (as well as retrieve status updates).

Of course, you couldn't access the movies directly from the visible swf, but once loading is done, the movies *should* be cached by the browser and *should* be available immediately upon request...

Again, just a thought - haven't actually tried anything like that myself.

Comment: "So crazy it might just work" :) I'll try it in the morning with the correct files. Not the simplest solution, but could work.

Comment: Please post your findings if you do give it a shot. I highly doubt that I'll have a chance to try it out myself and I'm now really curious to know whether or not it would work :)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work :( I had two swfs: 1 that had an FLVPlayback component playing 1 flv and setting up a LocalConnection as a receiver and another one that loaded 6 FLV files with LoaderMax and sent a message via Local Connection. The framerate on the first swf drops from 30 to 1FPS. I also created another swf just had mr.doob's stats in and got the same behaviour(drop to 1FPS). It might be the memory. The memory starts with 116, but when the videos kick in goes up to 384. It takes a few seconds after the load is complete for the framerate to return to normal(30FPS).

Comment: Yup. Might be a stretch, but is it possible to allocate memory initially somehow, then load the videos into the allocated chunks ?

Comment: In the end, luckily, it was an issue on my machine only (a combination of os issues with the Debug StandAlone player). The difference in speed between the standalone debug player and the browser is massive on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the bufferTime or do you think that the loading is limiting system resources?

Comment: I haven't tried increasing the buffer time, but I think the loading in the background is limiting the resources, since, so far, I've only tested locally.